# unresolved deltas with git bundle

Tags: git

I need to update a repository using `git bundle`.
This worked for a while and now starts failing with strange errors.

I tried to reproduce the situation in a local environment: ~/git contains the source repository and ~/git2 the target repository which should be updated.

```
$ cd git
$ git bundle create b-all --all --since=20.days
$ cd ../git2
$ git bundle verify ../git/b-all
[...]
The bundle requires these 18 refs:
[...]
../git/b-all is okay
$ git bundle unbundle ../git/b-all
fatal: pack has 35 unresolved deltas
error: index-pack died
$ git fetch ../git/b-all refs/*:refs/foo/*
[same error]
```

I tried to minimize the example with the following strange result:

```
$ git bundle create b-all --all                  --since=20.days   #error
$ git bundle create b-to --tags --remotes=origin --since=20.days   #error
$ git bundle create b-t  --tags                  --since=20.days   #works
$ git bundle create b-o         --remotes=origin --since=20.days   #works
```

In all cases `git bundle create` works fine and `git bundle verify` is happy, but in the error cases `git bundle unpack` dies because of unresolved deltas.

Any idea how to debug this further?

---

Remarks:

```
$ git rev-list --no-walk --remotes=origin|tee l-o|wc -l
354
$ git rev-list --no-walk --tags|tee l-t|wc -l
1120 #our CI server is pretty active here.
$ git rev-list --no-walk --remotes=origin --tags|tee l-ot|wc -l
1417 
$ echo $((354+1120))
1474 # some commits do have both a tag and a branch
$ diff <(sort -u l-ot) <(sort -u l-o l-t)
$ # no difference
```

Comment: Has it been more than 20 days since your last update via bundle? If so then you have missing commits between the latest commits that have actually been imported and the start of the new bundle. Make sure your new bundle goes back at least as far as the latest commits your destination repository already has.

Comment: That was my first idea, too. But increasing the time does not help and as you see with the example above `--tags` and `--remotes=origin` alone works without problems. Hence it should not be some missing older commit. - Also a missing commit should be detected by `git bundle verify`.

Comment: Does `git fsck --full` find any issues in your source repository? You can use `git rev-list --no-walk <other options>` (where other options are your `--all`, `--tags`, `--remotes=...` and `--since=...` bits) to see exactly which heads are being walked to populate the bundle. Comparing those lists for your test cases might yield something...

Comment: it says "requires these 18 refs", what are they? Use `git show -p <ref>` to investigate what is it.

Comment: @kan: Yes, the bundle requires those refs, but git also found them in the repository. Therefore it concludes "is ok". If one would be missing it would complain at exactly this step.